# Setting IsModified on EntityFramework Decimal Property

Tags: entity-framework, decimal

I'm somewhat new to EF, and trying to make an UPDATE method in REST style that will take one or more properties in an object and update the database with just those I passed in.

I have the code below working for several types.  However, i recently added System.Decimal, and am getting an error that I can't use the Property() method because my decimal field is not a Primitive or complex type.  The error occurs on the following line:

```
 pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).IsModified = true;
```

The actual error message is:

Additional information: The property 'Miles' on type 'Appointment' is not a primitive or complex property. The Property method can only be used with primitive or complex properties. Use the Reference or Collection method.

My property "Miles" is an 18,2 decimal in SQL and decimal on the EF class as well as my data model class.

I've spent two days searching for any clues or solutions, but got nowhere.  Help me obi wan kenobi, you're my only hope...

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutAppointment(int id,[FromBody] DTO.Appointment appointment)
    {
        // Check for invalid model and mis-matched ID
        if (!ModelState.IsValid){ return BadRequest(ModelState); }
        if (id != appointment.AppointmentID) { return BadRequest(); }

        // Create and populate an Appointment Entity which we will use for saving our data later
        Appointment tempAppt = new Appointment();
        tempAppt.AppointmentID = appointment.AppointmentID;
        db.Appointments.Attach(tempAppt);
        var pt = db.Entry(tempAppt);

        // Loop through all the properties on the object that was passed into this method
        //  and update the Entity with any that were provided.
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in appointment.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
            {
                switch (propertyInfo.PropertyType.ToString())
                {
                    case "System.Int32":
                        if ((int)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment) != -1)
                        {
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).CurrentValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment);
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).IsModified = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "System.Decimal":
                        if ((decimal)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment) != -1)
                        {
                            propertyInfo.SetValue(appointment, (decimal)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment));
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).IsModified = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "System.String":
                        if ((string)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment) != "NONE")
                        {
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).CurrentValue = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment);
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).IsModified = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        if ((DateTime)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment) != new DateTime(2099, 1, 1))
                        {
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).CurrentValue = (DateTime)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment);
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).IsModified = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "System.TimeSpan":
                        if ((TimeSpan)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment) != new TimeSpan(0))
                        {
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).CurrentValue = (TimeSpan)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment);
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).IsModified = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    //case "System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]":
                    case "System.Guid":
                        if ((Guid)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment) != new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                        {
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).CurrentValue = (Guid)propertyInfo.GetValue(appointment);
                            pt.Property(propertyInfo.Name).IsModified = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As usual, when i have a problem that takes more than a couple hours to solve, it comes down to something stupid.

My data/business object was using an upper case "M" on "Miles" and my database (and consequently EF) was using a lower case "m" on "miles".  Once I gave up and changed it to a data type that i had working, it became obvious it wasn't the type that was the issue.  Then I just had to stare at it long enough to notice the case problem.

As you were...

Comment: You should accept this as your answer. Exact same problem for me.